# How to do pre-treatment on surface and how to clean the glass surface after silanization?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, surface-chemistry

By Silanization, I want to treat surface of some spherical glass beads. Each bead is supposed to be shot in a particle launcher (like a bullet from a gun). I have some detailed question for the process:

1) Do you think that the hydrophobic coating which is created on the glass bead surface is durable enough that not to be removed or scratched by friction due to SOFT rubbing to the particle launcher tube?

2) Before silanization, should I perform any pre-treatment on glass surface? (e.g. pouting the glass in acid, or heating the glass surface, etc ...)

3) After I take out the glass from pool of silan, the glass surface is partially covered with reactant agents which is hardly cleaned with water. How should I clean the silanized surface after taking out from the pool? (using acetone and rubbing with a napkin is okay, etc)